# Gridview Button delete always returns False

Tags: vb.net, gridview, oracle10g, delete-file, popupwindow

In my coding [coding that I have used and has worked when not using a gridview button] always returns my confirmValue as False.

I was wondering why this is the case.
The popup completely ignores the Yes or No `"INPUT"` part on asking if `Continue with File Deletion?"` line of coding. It just automatically goes straight to my Vb.net coding with the confirm value as false.

Any suggestions why?

JavaScript

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

function onConfirm() {

    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");

    confirm_value.type = "hidden";

    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";

    if (confirm("Continue with File Deletion?")) {

        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        //alert("Yes was Selected. Article Selected Will Be Deleted!")

    } else {

        confirm_value.value = "No";
        //alert("No was Selected. Article Will Not Be Deleted.")
    }

    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);

}

</script>
```

Gridview:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Delete File"> 
   <ItemTemplate >
      <asp:button ID = "btnDelete" cssClass = "submit-btn small" Text = "Delete" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat = "server" OnClientClick = "OnConfirm()" OnClick = "DeleteFile" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle cssClass="grid_padding" />

</asp:TemplateField>
```

Vb.net to delete the row/file in the row when the button is clicked

```
Protected Sub DeleteFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")

    If confirmValue = "Yes" Then
        Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('Yes was Selected. File Will Be Deleted!');</script>")
        Dim filePath As String = CType(sender, Button).CommandArgument
        File.Delete(filePath)
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
    Else
        Response.Write("<script language=""javascript"">alert('No was Selected. File Will Not Be Deleted.');</script>")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it this way without using any additional form field (`confirmValue`):

JavaScript:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
function OnConfirm() {
    if (confirm("Continue with File Deletion?")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("No was Selected. Article Will Not Be Deleted.");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

GridView:

```html
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Delete File"> 
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:button ID = "btnDelete" cssClass = "submit-btn small" Text = "Delete" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>'
          runat = "server" OnClientClick = "return OnConfirm();" OnClick = "DeleteFile" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   <ItemStyle cssClass="grid_padding" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Notice **`return`** in `OnClientClick="return OnConfirm();"`

Code behind:

```vb
Protected Sub DeleteFile(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim filePath As String = CType(sender, Button).CommandArgument
    File.Delete(filePath)
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "DeleteMessage",
       "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Yes was selected. File was deleted!');
       document.location.href='" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "'; </script>")
End Sub
```

Additionally, if you are calling the code behind from within `UpdatePanel` then instead of `ClientScript` you need to use `ScriptManager`

```vb
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "DeleteMessage",
    "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Yes was selected. File was deleted!');
    document.location.href='" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri + "'; </script>", False)
```

Comment: Your coding does make it work now; however, it negates the option of the user selecting Yes or No. I added the return part to my javascript coding to make the change

Comment: By just adding return true and false to my javascript coding I am still forced to use my confirmValue = Request.Form . Is there a way to add that to your coding version??

Comment: Nevermind I found a way to do it. I changed `OnClientClick = "if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;"`

Comment: It does but doesn't give the option to allow the user to say no

Comment: if I do `type="submit"` nothing changes. the coding doesn't give the option to stop the deletion.

Comment: I added the missing `;` but the "No" option doesn't show up still.

Comment: @narue1992 Tested above code on one of my existing projects, there was a small typo (`OnConfirm`, capital O, case sensitive javascript!) and after fixing that everything works fine.